# DCG(again) creating abstrac tree in semantic actions

Tags: prolog, dcg

Here is some gramma wich represents tree

```
<tree> -> *
<tree> -> (<tree><tree>)
```

where `*` means `leaf` and couple of trees in parentheses describes root that sons are trees in parentheses.
i Have to rewrite that gramma to dcg and add semantic actions which will create abstrac tree of that tree whith `leaf/0` and `node/2` example `node(node(leaf,leaf),node(leaf,leaf))`
for any idea or source i will be gratefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my SWI-Prolog:

```
leaf_rule(leaf) --> "*".
tree_rule(X) --> leaf_rule(X), !.
tree_rule(node(X,Y)) --> "(", tree_rule(X), tree_rule(Y), ")".
```

In order to parse a string you need to call `phrase` predicate, for example:

```
phrase(tree_rule(X), "((**)*)", Rest).
```

Prolog will unify X with abstract representation of tree from string.

Comment: No need for the cut! And no need for leaf_rule//1.

Comment: cut makes it deterministic but yes leaf rule is not need but semantic actions are in { } that is just additional Logic Variable wich will uniy on the end